# PME on thick client node join in Ignite

Tags: ignite, gridgain, apacheignite

I am using Ignite 2.9.1 and in our Ignite cluster setup we have server nodes and thick client nodes. I found that when client node join the topology, it triggers PME but surprisingly it shouldn't as per below documentation:

[image]

Log snippet:
[image]

To cross verify I have gone through code of **ServerImpl(line 5390)** and **ClientImpl(line 2307)** and in both case I found it trigger discovery event post processing **NodeAddFinishedMessage**. Both leads to **GridDiscoveryManager(line 759)** and **GridCachePartitionExchangeManager(line 351 & 581)** which creates **GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture** for **ExchangeWorker**

In fact in whole code flow I didn't find any check which filters out Client node to generate GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture. Can anyone confirm the behavior?

Refer below screenshot of the code files:

**ServerImpl:**
[image]

**ClientImpl:**
[image]

**GridDiscoveryManager:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A thick client node join/leave still triggers PME, but it's another lightweight type of exchange, which just updates the topology version.

You can find more details regarding different PME types [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/%28Partition+Map%29+Exchange+-+under+the+hood) in the `Exchange type determination` section.

Comment: Thanks @Igor, that is exactly my understanding based on the Ignite code however documentation confused me. It seems correcting the document would make things more clear.